# vim end of line

Tags: vim

I want to view where lines end in gvim. I very often have spaces after statements and I don't want to have. How to toggle this editor feature?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
set list
```

That will show lots of stuff (see `:help 'list'` for more information).  If you want to just show the line endings, do this as well:

```
set lcs=eol:$,tab:\ \
```

(Note that there are two "backslash, space" pairs on the end of the line).  This prevents tabs from being highlighted.

You could alternatively do:

```
set lcs=eol:$,tab:\ \ ,trail:#
```

To make all trailing spaces as `#`.  Play with it to your hearts content and see:

```
:help 'listchars'
```

---

Alternatively, you can just highlight it with something like this:

```
syn match Error /\s\+$/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can highlight trailing whitespace like this: (lifted from http://ertius.org/blog/highlighting-trailing-whitespace-in-vim/)

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
autocmd Syntax * syn match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
```

This isn't a built-in toggleable feature, though; the above snippet would go in your config and would make this active all the time.

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to highlight anything by just doing a /character and hit enter.

for example /\n (enter) should show where the newlines are.

Comment: "I want to view where lines end in gvim."  -  My answer is how I address the very same issue all the time.

Comment: +1. I have to disagree that this does not answer poster's question. OP specifically asks for "toggling this feature". I'm just getting my feet wet with vim but what's simpler than this?